# Spellcheck on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, spell-checking

Is there any way that I can insert spell check on my textbox.

**PROCEDURE** 
1. When I type text on the multiline textbox it will display red wavy lines below the word that is mispelled.
2. When I click on the red wavy underlined mispelled word, it will display all suggested word.

**NOTE**
a. If this is not possible it will just display red wavy lines.
b. I'm also using IE8.
c. No buttons must be use. Textbox only.

I tried using javascriptspellchecker but it doesn't work on textbox. 

If you could give me some links that is similar with my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using IE8?  Upgrade to IE10 and spell check is built in.  It's also built in to Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Also, Stackoverflow is for programming questions.  This kind of question is a better fit for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: cannot upgrade it on windows xp. Our system is best viewed with ie8/ie9

Comment: Career advice: If you continue to develop code that "works best in X browser", you'll find your career options in the future to be limited. Especially if "X browser" is an old version of IE, such as IE8. I'd work to update your site and encourage XP users to use Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

try using the asp.net spell checker

http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=865

Comment: altough the asp.net one is simple . Try this one http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=jQuery

Comment: there must be no link buttons. When it loads it will display all possible mispelled words.

Comment: yeap so call the spell checking method on load.

Answer (score 1):

I know (and can suggest) the UltimateSpell control, that do what you ask for, but is not free.

http://www.karamasoft.com/Samples.aspx?component=UltimateSpell

Comment: that's what i'm looking for. Too bad its not free =(